# how to run flutter project via smartphone hotspot

Tags: flutter, debugging

now i have 1 smartphone and 1 laptop and there is no wifi access here, can i run my flutter project through my smartphone hotspot. just like companion on kodular

note: I don't use a USB cable for some reason

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wifi AVD plugin to debug your application wirelessly but you have to connect your device via USB for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out. You can use wireless adb connection
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb